# Is it possible make capacitors discharge like batteries do?

Tags: capacitor, batteries

This question is regarding the possibility of use of capacitors as batteries.

One impediment in this is that the capacitor quickly discharges unevenly.

[image]

But here's how a typical lithium ion battery discharges.

[image]

Is it possible to regulate the discharge of capacitor so that it discharges more evenly? Would there by any energy loss?

Let's say we have a capacitor which has 100 kJ of energy stored in it. I have a device to run which needs constant voltage and current. Is there a way I can use this capacitor to power the device so that the energy is released constantly? Is there a way to achieve this by adding external circuits which can do this?

Comment: You have the discharge curve formula right in front of you. Doesn't that answer your question? That formula directly derives from the differntial equation that defines what a capacitor is.

Comment: I'd say it's the capacitor that (dis)charges evenly. (Dis)charge it with a CC and you get a nice straight slope.

Comment: *One impediment in this is that the capacitor quickly discharges unevenly.* If you load it with a resistor, indeed you get an exponential curve. Load it with a **constant current** and you would get a linear discharge curve. Also realize that capacitors and batteries are completely different devices! If you want a capacitor that discharges like a battery then you don't understand what makes a capacitor work. A capacitor that would do that would **not** be called a capacitor. It would be called a **battery**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie call it whatever you want. The thing is I have a capacitor which has 100 KJ of energy stored in it. Now I have device to run which needs constant voltage and current. Now is there a way I can use this capacitor to power the device so that the energy is released constantly?

Comment: This is actually quite a neet questions, I could see the use of being able charge a capacitor very quickly, but discharge it very slowly, best of both worlds

Comment: @DR.Palson_PH.d  thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you could put a switchmode DC-DC converter<sup>1</sup> between the capacitor and the load. It would provide constant output voltage until the capacitor voltage drops too low to operate it. Obviously, you'd want the converter to be as efficient as possible.

The capacitor will discharge at constant power, which means that the current will increase as the voltage drops.

---

<sup>1</sup> Buck, boost or buck-boost, depending on the range of capacitor voltage relative to the output voltage.

Comment: Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2):

No, the discharge curve directly results from the differential equation that defines a capacitor. If a device discharges differently, it's not a capacitor.

Also, you're comparing apples and pears: In the lower diagram, the discharge is done with a constant current if we consider the horizontal axis to be proportional to time, in the upper diagram with a constant resistive load, so with a time-variant current.

You will need to sit down with the formulas a bit more!

Comment: I know that, thw whole point is that can we make capacitors discharge slowly, by some kind of external circuit arrangement. And the graph was only do demonstrate the trend of discharge.

Comment: If you want you can calculate the energy left in Wh versus time. You'll get a similar graph

Comment: no you can't invent such a circuit. That circuit would need to produce energy out of nowhere. You could only "undersell" your charge voltage for 99% of the time and regulate down to that.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/576055/291207

Comment: exactly what I'm saying: buck converter offers a voltage that is constantly below the voltage of your capacitor. Or a boost that discharges your capacitor faster at constant current consumption; there's no free lunch.

Comment: No free lunch recquired, constant current is what we want

Comment: Please read the edit, the end goal is to run the device, as long as it's achieved everything else is fine. I don't know why or what you are disagreeing with. Can't we give a constant supply of current to the device we need to run using a capacitor. Yes or no? If yes how? That's the question. No one is talking about having a free lunch. Energy ofcourse is conserved, we just want to modulate the release of energy

Comment: To be precise, if we plot the product of I and V over time. The area under the curve is the same in both discharges. So energy is the same. But I want the  curve to look flat, like the battery curve instead of exponential curve of the typical capacitor discharge

Comment: Also where have I said, in my question, that the peak voltage value of capacitor is the voltage value I need as a constant source. You are assumimg it on your own. Lets say the capacotpr voltage is 100V. Its fine if I get 3V constantly for a longer time

Comment: well, then your question all along was not about the capacitor, but "how do I generate a 3V from a 100V - 5V"

Comment: Morelike how do I generate 3V from rapidly discharging 100 V capacitor

Comment: the fact that it's a transistor doesn't matter at all, but I agree: it's a "how do I generate a voltage from a rapidly changing voltage"

Comment: yes exactly. This is the idea

Answer (score 2):

If your load requires a constant voltage then you’ll need a DC/DC converter; this can be boost, buck or buck-boost depending on the relative voltages of the capacitor and the load.  Since the energy stored in the capacitor is proportional to the square of the voltage, once the voltage drops off significantly, the current will increase in inverse proportion and so the remaining energy will be extracted quite quickly.  Bear in mind that batteries typically have *much* higher capacity than capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. The energy stored in a capacitor is given by the equation E = 1/2 CV^2. That is, the energy in the cap is proportional to the square of the voltage on the cap.

This means that, if you remove 1/2 of the energy in a cap, the voltage MUST drop by 30%. If you remove 80% of the energy in a cap, the voltage MUST drop by 65%.

The more complicated answer is that it's pretty trivial. You put a switching DC to DC converter on the output of the cap. As the energy in the cap is depleted, its voltage drops, but the DC-DC converter output will remain constant. This will continue until the capacitor voltage falls below the minimum input voltage of the converter.

Comment: so the answer is yes. We can use DC to DC booster to provide constant voltage. Also refer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/576055/291207.

Comment: why are you saying no??

Comment: @MrGreenGold - Good DC-DC converters with a relatively high current output (such as you'd expect from a lithium battery replacement) are expensive.

Comment: you mean expensive in terms of money right. I hope there are minimal energy losses in doing so. So it works right.